# Calling an executable from within Python / Django web application running on IIS

Tags: python, windows, django, iis, executable

I have a Python / Django application which is supposed to call an external windows binary and get its output at some point. And it does so when tested via 'python manage.py shell'.

But when it is run from within the web browser, which is served by IIS, the external application is not executed.

Is IIS blocking something on the way? Can this be avoided?

Any help is much appreciated.

oMat

Comment: Python is not "served by IIS". How are you running the Django project?

Comment: And what exception do you get?

Comment: Could it be a path issue? Are you referencing the executeable with a full path?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a permissions issue. when you run from the shell, you're using the user that run the `python manage.py shell` command. When serving requests from the IIS you're using its user (IUSR or something like that). Try giving execution permission on the executable file to the Everyone group just to see if it helps.